# Assign value to logged in user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a Django app where I am trying to assign a `bank` variable to each user, set to 100 by default.

I have the following model in `models.py` :

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.FloatField(default=100)
```

which is then used in `views.py`:

```
class BitgainzView(View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
        context = {'bank': user.wallet.bank}
        return render(self.request, "index.html", context)
```

I then print `bank` in my html page.

Two problems with this :

1. if user is logged in :
   I get the error `Exception Value: User has no wallet.` which I think is because the schema for Wallet was created in relation to User, but never initialised for each user.
2. if user is not logged in :
   Then the context in `BitgainzView()` cannot be loaded, and I am also getting an error. Should I make separate views in that case ? Or should I treat different cases inside this function ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use try and except. if code finds user.wallet.bank, then ok else create a wallet instance for that user. Thats the simplest way.

Comment: That works !! Thank you very much @sandeep . Regarding 2), what would you say is the best approach when a user is not logged in ?

Comment: what do want to do if user is not logged in? and you don't have write query to get current loggen in user. just write user = self.request.user . it will give current logged in user instance. For not logged in user, you can check if self.request.user.is_authenticated.

Comment: @LouisGRIMALDI use [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), all non-logged in users would be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Both self.request.user.is_authenticated and LoginRequiredMixin work ! Thank you guys this is amazing.